# Chilkat message ID generation methodology?

Tags: email, encoding, message-digest

The Chilkat proprietary email API concocts message IDs with formats like this:

> CHILKAT-MID-862e2615-b706-5239-b049-38ded70b2a77

How is that value calculated? Is that a standard unix digest of some kind, or is it an unknown code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysis, it appears to be a standard Windows [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).